# How to access a specific part of a list element, using loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list which is

```
a = [(0, 0.6249995), (1, 0.12500015), (2, 0.12500016), (3, 0.12500015)]
```

0,1,2,3 being topics based on LDA modelling and 0.6249995, 0.12500015, 0.12500016 and 0.12500015 being the probabilities.

I need to access only the element which has the maximum probability, i.e.(0, 0.6249995).

How do I write a for loop to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(a[0]) - 1):
    for j in range(len(a)):
    print(max(a[j][1]))
```

But this is not working, it is only giving me all the probabilities.

What changes can I make to this?

Comment: `max(a, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: You could add a variable before the loop to store the max value, and as you go through the loop if a[j][1] > max_value set max_value = a[j][1] so when you exit the loop your answer is the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do (Alexander Lekontsev beat me to it):

```
print(max(a, key=lambda i:i[-1])) #prints element
print(a.index(max(a, key=lambda x:x[-1]))) #prints index of max probability
```

What `lambda` does is that the max function evaluates based on the given criteria (last index of each element in list `a`), and returns the tuple with the max probability.

Comment: In theory there could be more than one item with probability= max probability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `max()` function with a lambda expression to get the second item of the tuple:

```
a = [(0, 0.6249995), (1, 0.12500015), (2, 0.12500016), (3, 0.12500015)]
max_prob = max(a, key=lambda t: t[1])
print(max_prob)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0.6249995)
```

Comment: In theory there could be more than one item with probability= max probability.

Comment: Thank you @jignatius, tuple is ideally what I should expected to work with. Erroneously thought it to be list:)

Comment: @MihirBelgaonkar It is a list - a list of tuples.

Comment: Got it! just one more doubt. How do make the output that I get from max_prob iterable? Any idea? TIA.

Comment: @MihirBelgaonkar A tuple is iterable. You can access the items directly like `max_prob[1]` or use tuple unpacking: `id, value = max_prob`. You can also iterate a tuple: `for I in max_prob`. And you can unpack it with the `*` operator and pass the contents to a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
a = [(0, 0.6249995), (1, 0.12500015), (2, 0.12500016), (3, 0.12500015)]

new = list()
for i in a:
    new.append(i[1])
print(max(new))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [(0, 0.6249995), (1, 0.12500015), (2, 0.12500016), (3, 0.12500015)]

from itertools import groupby
item = next(groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True),
            key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(list(item[1]))
```

output:

```
[(0, 0.6249995)]
```

In theory there could be more than one item with probability= max probability. This accounts for such possibility, e.g.

if

```
data = [(0, 0.0249995), (1, 0.12500015), (2, 0.12500016), 
        (3, 0.12500015), (4, 0.3), (5, 0.3)]
```

the output is:

```
[(4, 0.3), (5, 0.3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Yes ideally I would also need to access multiple elements, if the max probabilities are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an easy to understand way to do it;

```
import sys

maxVal = sys.float_info.min
for t in a:
    if t[1] > maxVal:
        maxElement = t
        maxVal = t[1]

print(maxElement)
```

Since the list contains tuples, each value of the tuple could be accessed by t[0], t[1]

If there could be more than one element with max probability, you could use another list and append to it. As shown below;

```
import sys

maxList = []
maxVal = sys.float_info.min
for t in a:
    if t[1] >= maxVal:
        maxVal = t[1]
        maxList.append(t)

print(maxList)
```

Comment: This made it so much more easier! Thank you